# WordPress Responsive Mobile Menu plugin problem

Tags: wordpress, mobile, plugins, drop-down-menu, responsive

I am trying to set a mobile menu with Responsive Mobile Menu plugin on WordPress with white drop-down theme. But it's not working.

I edited the details in the theme but in result I got the half opened drop-down showing only first letter of all page names instead of showing drop-down theme with proper width opening

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and found this topic while googling.

I tried many things and solved this problem by making this steps:

From COntainer setting , go apparence and change width value

[image]